# TypeError: _firebase_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.default.auth is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I created login code for my website using reactjs. when I edit the codes and run the program, it will be an error.

heres an error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3REwr.png)

I am already uploaded the code on codesandbox
[the link for the code](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-ride-i66nw?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the future, please include a minimal working example of your code and what the error is in your question.

That said, the reason you are getting `...default.auth is not a function` is because the default export of `./firebase/firebase.js` is a [`firebase.database.Reference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference), not the general [`firebase` namespace](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase) you were expecting.

```
export default fireDb.database().ref(); // A firebase.database.Reference
```

However as you named the variable `fireDb`, it is implied that it is an instance of Firebase Database, not a reference. I recommend renaming your variables to reflect this.

The file `./firebase/firebase.js`:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/database'

const firebaseConfig = { ... };
// Initialize Firebase
const fireApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default fireApp.database();
```

Then, to get an instance of [`firebase.auth.Auth`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth) from a [`firebase.database.Database`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Database), you would use `fireDb.app.auth()`.

The file `./App.js`:

```
import fireDb from "./firebase/firebase";
/* ... */
const handleLogout = () => {
  fireDb.app.auth().signOut();
};
```